# Extract number from a list in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python v2.x Windows 64bit.
The question is, I would like to extract a number (102) from a list, but I can only get a part of if.

Here is a list:

```
data = ['getmotors \r', 'Parameter,Value\r', 'Brush_RPM,0\r', 'Brush_mA,0\r', 'Vacuum_RPM,0\r', 'Vacuum_mA,0\r', 'LeftWheel_RPM,1800\r', 'LeftWheel_Load%,42\r', 'LeftWheel_PositionInMM,10452\r', 'LeftWheel_Speed,102\r', 'RightWheel_RPM,1800\r', 'RightWheel_Load%,42\r', 'RightWheel_PositionInMM,9650\r', 'RightWheel_Speed,102\r', 'ROTATION_SPEED,0.00\r', 'SideBrush_mA,0\r', '\x1a']
```

How to extract the speed of LeftWheel_Speed (102)?
I tried `data[9][-2]`, but what I get is ‘`2`’ rather than ‘`102`’.

Comment: how about data[9][-4:-1]?

Comment: @GarrettR That would fail for the others.

Comment: `float(data[9].strip().split(',')[1])` works everywhere except in the first two elements as they don't have a value. Using `strip` to remove the `\r`

Comment: @Amber.G ... Do accept one of the below answers to close your question otherwise comments if not working for you...

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.search` and a regex pattern, you can extract the integer value from the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'\d+', data[9])
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 19), match='102'>
>>> re.search(r'\d+', data[9]).group(0)
'102'
>>> speed = int(re.search(r'\d+', data[9]).group(0))
>>> speed
102
```

Here, `re.search(r'\d+', data[9])` will return a match if data[9] has any decimal characters. Then retrieving this decimal characters using `.group(0)` and finally convert them to integer, using `int()` built-in method

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int(data[9][-4:-1])+1
103
```

Use `iterable[start:end]` to get a subset of them.

Another thing you can do is, if you want to get a single integer from a string, is something along the lines of (python2.x):

```
s = "test123\n"
x = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s))
```

In Python3, filter returns a `filter object` which is an iterable. You can turn it into a list and join them for the same functional result.

```
s = "test123\n"
x = int(''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s))))
```

Note that this does not take into account separated numbers. For example, `s = "123test456"` will return `123456`. If you want them separated, you will need to use something a bit more clever.

```
>>> s = "\n123test456\n"
>>> nums = map(int, ''.join([x if x.isdigit() else ' ' for x in s]).split())
>>> print(nums)
[123, 456]
```

Again, in python3, map returns a `map object`, so you just have to convert it to a list.

```
>>> s = "\n123test456\n"
>>> nums = list(map(int, ''.join([x if x.isdigit() else ' ' for x in s]).split()))
>>> print(nums)
[123, 456]
```

Comment: No particular reason. Really just to show that it successfully parsed as an int and can therefore be used in arithmetic functions.

Comment: +1 one because this is the only answer that comes close both providing a solution, and addressing the underlying cause: the questioner's total ignorance of slicing lists in python. He doesn't need string functions or regex, he needs to spend an afternoon with Dive Into Python.

Comment: This has the potential to fail if the digits are not always on the same index postion...which is not one of OP's statements.

Comment: This answer can't be generalized.

Comment: I'm well aware it can't be generalized, but OP seems to be accessing it right now with `data[9][-2]` so I'm guessing it's not dynamic.

Comment: Updated. This should be plenty for OP.

Answer (score 2):

If all the items in the list that contain a single `,` can be considered key-value pairs, you can turn the data into a dictionary. That makes it easy to access the values that you are interested in.

```
datadict = {}
for item in data:
    key_value = item.strip().split(',')
    if len(key_value) == 2:
        key, value = key_value
        datadict[key] = value
print(datadict['RightWheel_Speed'])  # 102
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run your code, however, we got an error "list" object has no attribute 'strip'. (yes, data is a list)

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be item.strip(). I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

at index 9 in the list the element is a string `'LeftWheel_Speed,102\r'`, [-1] will display the `'\r'` character, and thus [-2] will display the `2`.  A string in python is list type, so you are looking at the second to last character. you need to split the string for each data element like:

```
data[9].split(',')[1]
```

which first splits the string into 2 strings at the comma and print `102`, but beware it still contains the `\r` character which you might want to remove:

```
data[9].split(',')[1][:-1]
```

`[:-1]` will slice off the last character of the string (which is a list so you can do list slicing)

EDIT: as commented below, `'102\r'.strip()` would be a more complete answer to removing special characters as it would remove them all

Comment: The `\r` can be removed using `strip`.

Comment: `str.strip`. Not `string.strip`. :-)

Comment: Nope. `str` and `string` are two different things in Python. See [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#module-string). Good that you've edited now.

Answer (score 1):

```
print data[9].split(',')[1]
```

You can split it on ',' and display the second string

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.